# Close the current tab with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I see that in Tools -> Options -> Keyboard you can set Keyboard shortcuts for a large number of tasks. I tried searching for "Close" and these are the results, amongst a few others:

- File.Close
- File.CloseAllButThis
- File.CloseProject
- File.CloseSolution

If I set File.Close to be Ctrl+W (Honestly, why doesn't Microsoft innately support such a universal shortcut is beyond me) it mostly works, however if I have both the code-behind and the Designer view open for a form, it closes both tabs. Should I be setting a different command, or am I stuck with this? It's a small inconvenience, but it really irritates me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know if it's the same in VS2010, but in VS2012 this command is called "Window.CloseDocumentWindow" and it is mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> by default, to mirror <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> for closing application-level windows.

I believe the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut was first brought to Microsoft Windows by Adobe Photoshop, a carry-over from Apple OS X, where Adobe seems to have remapped all of the <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+* shortcuts to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+*. On OS X, <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> only closes windows, but the application stays resident. One uses <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to quit applications, instead. As the window *is* the application in Windows, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is kind of a misnomer, but it has gotten more popular for some applications like web browsers to support it.

Given the market dominance of MS Windows over Apple OS X for desktop operating systems, it would seem that the F4-style shortcuts are "more universal" than the W/Q ones.

Comment: Great, thanks, 2010 is also CloseDocumentWindow! And thanks for the explaination as well, a very strong argument for sure. Between web browsers and Steam's instant message client I'm just so used to Ctrl-W, I never would've thought of Ctrl-F4.

Answer (score 1):

Use CTRL+F4 to close current window, to close all window of visual studio and shut down use - ALT+F4 .

Comment: CTRL + Function Keys are so cumbersome.  My hand doesn't stretch that far.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Keyboard [Apply "visual studio code" additional keyboard mapping scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0psT.jpg)